# "Screen scrape" with Jsoup with element who has ID

Tags: java, android, jsoup

All- I can not figure how to get the value of an element that has an ID. I have this so far

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = null;
        try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www3.rtd-denver.com/schedules/getSchedule.action?runboardId=123&routeId=0&routeType=1&serviceType=3").get();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        docTitle = doc.select("table[id=\"td1-7\"] [class=\"datacell\"]").first().text(); //NOT SURE HERE
        return null;
```

What I want is to get the value of `<td id="td2-6" class="datacell">`I get a force close when I use this so I know it is not right. How can I get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you should be using:

```
doc.select("td#td2-6.datacell").first().text()
```

Or, since IDs have to be unique, just:

```
doc.select("td#td2-6").first().text()
```

However, I doubt that'd give you a force close, unless it found no elements (in which case `first()` is probably null).

If those still aren't working, and since you didn't provide any LogCat error context, check if `doc` is null, in which case your initial `Jsoup.connect()` failed.

Comment: @androidcurious Seems I beat your own answer by only 27 seconds... glad you've got it all working now! :)